# i am having issues with an outdated version of iced-tea and have tried doin f install and no luck

Tags: icedtea

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/icedtea-netx_1.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: error processing package icedtea-netx:i386 (--configure):
 package icedtea-netx:i386 1.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 cannot be configured because icedtea-netx:amd64 is at a different version (1.5-1ubuntu1)
```

Comment: The two packages `icedtea-netx:i386 1.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1` and `icedtea-netx:amd64 1.5-1ubuntu1` conflict, and cannot be guaranteed to interoperate.

Comment: Is there a work around so I can use my computer? Can't use Software Center let alone any websites that need an updated flash plug in.